# Parse Alamofire result swift

Tags: swift, alamofire, nsdictionary, swifty-json

I'm very lost parsing the following response from an `AF` request – `let json = result as! NSDictionary` – in Swift:

```
{
    errors =     (
    );
    get = statistics;
    parameters =     {
        country = germany;
    };
    response =     (
                {
            cases =             {
                "1M_pop" = 14303;
                active = 317167;
                critical = 4179;
                new = "+15161";
                recovered = 863300;
                total = 1200006;
            };
            continent = Europe;
            country = Germany;
            day = "2020-12-08";
            deaths =             {
                "1M_pop" = 233;
                new = "+380";
                total = 19539;
            };
            population = 83900328;
            tests =             {
                "1M_pop" = 347331;
                total = 29141172;
            };
            time = "2020-12-08T09:15:08+00:00";
        }
    );
    results = 1;
}
```

Any idea how to get the actual case numbers, i.e. for example the number of `new` cases?

So far I have tried the following (error throwing) approach:

```
if let responseDict = result as? NSDictionary {
                            if let data = responseDict.value(forKey: "response") as?
                                [NSDictionary] {
                                
                                // Get case numbers
                                guard let cases = data[0]["cases"] else { return }
                                guard let casesPerOneMil = cases[0] as! Int else { return }
                                print(casesPerOneMil)
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Any attempts? Do you know how dictionaries and array works? How to access the value of a Dictionary with a key? If yes, JSON is only Dictionary, Array, String, Numbers (and null). So Just start with `let response = json["response"]` (and that's an response Array). Etc. But, `Codable` might be a good idea to use.

Comment: Sorry – have included what I've tried so far in the question!

Comment: To debug, you need to know is `cases` nil? is `casesPerOneNil` nil? Or even throwing an error to crash (I wouldn't use the `as!`, but `as?`), and if that's the case, what's the error message? But clearly `cases` is a `Dictionary` not an Array. So `cases[0]` should crash and give an expected error message in console. It should be `cases["1M_pop"]` instead.

Comment: `guard let casesPerOneMil = cases["1M_pop"] as! Int else { return }` returns `Value of type 'Any' has no subscripts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically don't use `NS...` collection types in Swift at all, use native types.
And don't use `value(forKey`, use key subscription.

And you have to conditional downcast `Any` to the expected concrete type.

There is another mistake: The object for `cases` is a dictionary, note the `{}` and you have to get the value for `casesPerOneMil` with key subscription, too

```
if let responseDict = result as? [String:Any], 
   let dataArray = responseDict["response"] as? [[String:Any]],
   let firstDataItem = dataArray.first {
        
        // Get case numbers
        guard let cases = firstDataItem["cases"] as? [String:Any] else { return }
        guard let casesPerOneMil = cases["1M_pop"] as? Int else { return }
        print(casesPerOneMil)
    }
}
```